# For loop inside of case statement Bash

Tags: for-loop, switch-statement

I currently have a case statement where I define every option 0-10, but I find it cluttered and unnecessary. I thought using a for loop would work, but when I say, choose option 1, it will give the correct output, but also list several "Invalid options..

```
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
    options=("${var[@]}" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "${var[0]}")
            echo "${cmd[0]}"
                ;;
        "${var[1]}")
            echo "${cmd[1]}"
                ;;
        "${var[2]}")
            echo "${cmd[2]}"
                ;;
        "${var[3]}")
            echo "${cmd[3]}"
                ;;
        "${var[4]}")
            echo "${cmd[4]}"
                ;;
        "${var[5]}")
            echo "${cmd[5]}"
                ;;
        "${var[6]}")
            echo "${cmd[6]}"
                ;;
        "${var[7]}")
            echo "${cmd[7]}"
                ;;
        "${var[8]}")
            echo "${cmd[8]}"
                ;;
        "${var[8]}")
            echo "${cmd[8]}"
                ;;
        "${var[9]}")
            echo "${cmd[9]}"
                ;;
        "${var[10]}")
            echo "${cmd[10]}"
                ;;

        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
done
```

This is what I tried instead:

```
 PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("${var[@]}" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
for (( i=0; i<=10; i++ )) ; do
    case $opt in
        "${var[${i}]}")
            echo "${cmd[${i}]}"
                ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
done
```

Maybe I'm just using the for loop incorrectly, any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: `select` is itself a loop. Use of `for .. loop` is unnecessary here.

Comment: Try `select opt in "${options[@]}"; do [[ -n $opt ]] && echo "${cmd[$REPLY]}"; done`.

Comment: That works! except for var and cmd start at 0 instead of 1. I do appreciate the answer. I should be able to figure out a solution from here. Thank you!